# Matrix TransformPoints vs TransformVectors

Tags: .net, gdi+

What is, in a "for dummies" interpretation, the difference between
*System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix*

**`TransformPoints(pointsArray)`** <==> **`TransformVectors(pointsArray)`** ?

Edit:
there is also a `VectorTransformPoints(...)` method, by the way... :)

Answer (score 3):

[Matrix::TransformPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformpoints.aspx) will translate, rotate and scale the points passed to it.

[Matrix::TransformVectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformvectors.aspx) will only rotate and scale the points while ignoring the translation.

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) tells me that [Matrix::VectorTransformPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.vectortransformpoints.aspx) simply forwards it's argument to [Matrix::TransformVectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.transformvectors.aspx).